# Importing XML in HTML with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to import a XML-file into a HTML document with Javascript.

It works fine for Firefox, but it doesn't work for IE-10 and Chrome.

My script:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","xml_input.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
```

I think they changed the XMLHttpRequest again but I can't find it's replacement anywhere.  I'm hoping someone on this site can help me.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using a server of some kind? If you're testing off of a local address, e.g. `file://whatever/your/thing/is` you won't be able to make any HTTP requests by default unless you're in Firefox or Safari.

If you are using a server, do you get any errors in your console?
Can you see the request being attempted in the network tab?

Answer (score 1):

How about importing jquery into your project and using its wonderful $.ajax function. It will figure out the stuff under the covers (XMLHTTP) and you won't have to worry about this anymore. You want this to be abstracted away!.